# Show on-screen keyboard when textbox clicked

Tags: vba

I've built a on-screen keyboard for a surveillance system made in VBA. I need it so that when the user clicks on the textbox to enter the data, the on-screen keyboard I've made, shows up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`_Enter()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa211374(v=office.11)) event that fires when a user clicks inside the textbox control.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    frmKeyboard.Show
End Sub
```

For a more complete solution, you may want to wrap the keyboard showing/hiding events in a VBA class so you can more easily apply it to the different text boxes on your form. That way you don't have to repeat all of your code for each text box on your form. Just something to explore for down the road.  :-)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much!